# Program similar to getharmony.net to extract guitar notes

Tags: windows, open-source, music

[getharmony.net](http://getharmony.net/) was a very **interesting web** page where you could get the notes of a song with *guitar through a spectogram* and **make a tab** to interpret it. Unfortunately it is down, but I would like to know if there is an alternative that offers the same tools or if this page has moved to another domain.

Demonstration:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NlLGGMNBhkw

It should be noted that I have already tried some alternatives with *Capo for MacOS*, *yalp.io*, *guitaa.com* and *chordify*, but it does not give me the results that I expect, since the song that I put does not have chords, rather it is a plucking than the page or program interprets it as chords.

I appreciate any suggestions as I would like to extract the tab of a song.